# Splitting using regex is giving unwanted empty strings

Tags: python, regex

In python, I'm am executing this:

```
>>> re.split("(hello|world|-)", 'hello-world')
```

---

I am expecting this: 
`['hello', '-', 'world']`

however, I am getting this: 
`['', 'hello', '', '-', '', 'world', '']`

where is this `''` coming from?

I am using python 3 in case it matters

---

## Edit

Many of you are saying I could split it on `-` however, I want to extract `tokens` if that makes sense. Example if I had `"hellohello---worldhello"`. I want it to return

`['hello', 'hello', '-', '-', '-', 'world', 'hello']`

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `str.partition` for this? `'hello-world'.partition('-')`: --> `('hello', '-', 'world')`

Comment: I could do that, but if I had `hello--world`. I would like it to return `['hello', '-', '-', 'world']`

Comment: I can't see that it's possible to achieve your aim unless the tokens are always "hello" "-" and "world". Otherwise how would the regex engine know that "hellohello" contained two items of interest?

Comment: Why wouldn't it know? I tried on http://www.regexr.com. Have a look at this screen shot. It shows it matches all tokens. http://imgur.com/uGYoxV2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The same holds for the end of the string:

You could always use `filter` to control your list if this is your concern.

```
>>> filter(None, re.split('(hello|world|-)', 'hellohello---worldhello'))
['hello', 'hello', '-', '-', '-', 'world', 'hello']
```

Or use `findall` to grab your matches.

```
>>> re.findall('(hello|world|-)', 'hellohello---worldhello')
['hello', 'hello', '-', '-', '-', 'world', 'hello']
```

Comment: I could do that, but it would work for this case only. Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Idk who answered first, @isedev or you. I think it was you so I'm marking yours as the answer. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The extra output elements are because you are asking re to split the string on e.g. hello, so it tries to tell you what is before hello, what is between hello and '-', etc.  All are empty strings.

If you change it to :

`re.split("(-)", 'hello-world')`

You will get the desired result

`['hello', '-', 'world']`